# Conditional expectation of $E(\max(X,a)\mid\min(X,a))$ when $X$ is exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> I am trying to compute the conditional expectation $$E\left[\max{(X,a)} \mid \min{(X,a)}\right]$$ where $X\sim \exp(a)$ and $a$ is a constant.

I set $U=\min{(X,a)},W=\max{(X,a)}$, and computed the joint distribution as 
$$F_{UW}(u,w)=\begin{cases}P(X\le u,a\le w)+P(X\le w,a\le u)-P(X\le u,a\le u)& u<w\\P(X\le w,a\le w) &w<u\end{cases}$$

Then I don't know how to proceed. Can I differentiate $F_{UW}$ to find the joint density? Also, is there any easy way to compute without finding the joint density?

These is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75732/conditional-expectation-of-maxx-y-and-minx-y-when-x-y-are-iid-and-ex), but it involves two continuous r.v.

Comment: $X\sim\exp(a)$ is ambiguous.  Does it mean $X$ has an exponential distribution whose expected value is $a$, so that $\Pr(X>x) = e^{-x/a}$, or does it mean $X$ has an exponential distribution whose intensity is $a$, so that its expected value is $1/a$ and $\Pr(X>x) = e^{-ax}$? $\qquad$

Comment: In view of the serious troubles several answerers got into, trying to answer this question below, here is the answer: for every nonnegative $x$, $$E(\max(X,x)\mid \min(X,x))=\min(X,x)+E(X)\,\mathbf 1_{\min(X,x)=x}.$$

Comment: On dimensional grounds, it should be the expected value that is $a$.  An expression such as $\min(X,a)$ would make no sense if $X$ was a time and $a$ was a rate.

Comment: @Did Your suggestion is obviously wrong, since you expect that the maximum will be equal to the minimum (under certain event).

Comment: @Did Your answer is wrong. On $X<x$, $LHS=x>X=RHS$. It's $x+E(X)[\min(X,x)=x]$ instead.

Comment: @A.S. Indeed, there is a typo in my first comment. The correct answer is $$E(\max(X,x)\mid\min(X,x))=x+E(X)\mathbf 1_{\min(X,x)=x},$$ while the formula in my first comment gives $E(X\mid\min(X,x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things, if you write $$\max{(X,a)}=X+a-\min{(X,a)}$$ so that \begin{align}E\left[\max{(X,a)} \mid \min{(X,a)}\right]&=E\left[X+a-\min{(X,a)} \mid \min{(X,a)}\right]\\[0.2cm]&=E\left[X \mid \min{(X,a)}\right]+a-\min{(X,a)}\tag{1}\end{align}

---

**Edit:** To proceed (after correcting an obvious mistake that was pointed out), observe that 
\begin{align}E[X\mid \min{(X,a)}=y]&=\left.\begin{cases}y, & y<a\\y+E[X], &y= a\end{cases}\right\}=y+E[X]\mathbf 1_{\{y=a\}}\end{align} where the second case is due to the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. Hence \begin{align}E[X\mid \min{(X,a)}]&=\min{(X,a)}+E[X]\mathbf 1_{\{\min{(X,a)}=a\}}=\min{(X,a)}+E[X]\mathbf 1_{\{X\ge a\}}\end{align}
which, by substitution in $(1)$, gives the result
\begin{align}E\left[\max{(X,a)} \mid \min{(X,a)}\right]&=a+E[X]\mathbf 1_{\{X\ge a\}}
\end{align}

Comment: Is it any simpler to compute $E(X\mid\min(X,a))$ than $E(\max(X,a)\mid\min(X,a)))$?

Comment: The revised version confuses the (trivial) conditional expectation $E(X\mid A)$ with $P(A)\ne0$, with the conditional expectation $E(X\mid Y)$ with respect to $\sigma(Y)$. Note that, if $\min(X,a)<a$ then $\min(X,a)=X$, hence $E(X\mid\min(X,a))=\min(X,a)$ on the event $[\min(X,a)<a]$, not what is written in the post.

Comment: @Did I corrected the "serious trouble", so it would be appropriate to update your status for your feedback to remain constructive.

Comment: I understand your approach now! Thank you. But may you briefly state where you made an mistake before? I want to learn from that in case I made the same mistake in the future.

Comment: If $y=a$, is it OK to write $E(X|\min(X,a)=y)=E(X| X\ge a)$? I am a little confused about this point.

Comment: You seem more concerned about freely casting doubts on the constructiveness of my feedback than about answering the OP's confusion, why is that? *Once you will have answered the OP*, and only then, you might want to explain what was not fully constructive in my first comment. Or not.

Comment: @JohnZHANG Yes, of course, (let $Y:=\min{\{X,a\}}$ to save space) my mistake was that for $y<a$ I wrote $E[X\mid Y=y]=E[X\mid X<a]$ instead of the correct $E[X\mid Y=y]=y$, because if I know that $Y=y$ and $y<a$ then I know indeed that $X=y$ and not only that $X<a$. Now, for your second question, if we know $Y=y$ and $y=a$ (it cannot be $y>a$) then all we know is that $X>a$, so I am rather positive that we can write it.

Comment: @JohnZHANG So the method (was highlighted also elsewhere) is to calculate $E[X\mid \min{(X,a)}=y]$ for every possible $y$, to obtain a closed expression $E[X\mid Y=y]=f(y)$ and from this to go directly to $E[X\mid Y]=f(Y)$ and you are done.

Comment: @JimmyR. Thanks for your explanation.  So what I am confusing is what's the definition of $E[X\mid \min(X,a)=y]$. Suppose we denote $A=\{\min(X,a)=y\}$ be an event. If $y=a$, then we know $A=\{X\ge a\}$, and $P(A)=P(X\ge a)>0$. And we know by definition $E[X\mid A]=\frac{E(X1_{A})}{P(A)}$ provided $P(A)>0$ and we can calculate the expression. If $y<a$, then $A=\{X= y\}$. Since $P(A)=0$, we can't use the same definition as above. But we know $E[X\mid X]=X$, hence $E[X\mid X=y]=y$. So  $E[X\mid \min(X,a)=y]=E[X\mid A]=E[X\mid X=y]=y$.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @JimmyR. In other words, there are two definitions for $E(X|A)$ and hence two approaches to find the form of $E(X\mid A)$, depending on whether $P(A)>0$ or not.

Comment: @JohnZHANG I think your understanding is fine, I cannot see any flow. I would only avoid the term "two definitions". There is one definition for each case $P(A)=0$ and $P(A)>0$. However, I think of it a little differently. I think of $X\mid A$ as a random variable and am trying then to figure out the distribution of $X\mid A$. So, when I have $X\mid X=y$, then this is degenerate random variable and therefore indeed $E[X\mid X=y]=y$. When I have $X\mid X>a$ then I know that $f_{X\mid X>a}(x)=\frac{f_X(x)\mathbf 1_{X>a}}{1-F(a)}$ and calculate the expectation accordingly.

Comment: @JohnZHANG To be clear: When $P(A)=0$ there is no clear definition about how to define the conditional probability. See here for further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event

Comment: @JimmyR. Thanks for your effort. Your answer and comments are very helpful.

Comment: @JohnZHANG You are welcome!! I forgot to say, that the problem with the approach with the differentiation is that now if we let $A:=a$ (instead of $Y$ in the other post) then $A$ is a degenerate random variable without a density! So, you do not have that $F'_A(x)=f_A(a)$. But, perhaps there is some other manipulation, that I did not try.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Use the Law of Total Expectation, partitioning on the events of $X\leq a$ and $X>a$.

Also:
$\mathsf E(\max \{X, a\}\mid\min\{X,a\}) ~ = ~ {\mathsf E(a~\mathsf 1_{\min\{X,a\}<a}+X~\mathsf 1_{\min\{X,a\}=a}\mid \min\{X,a\})}$

Comment: The probability also need to be condition of $\min\{X, a\}$. It will be better to work out the deterministic conditional expectation given $\min\{X, a\} = b$ first.

Comment: Are you suggesting that $E(\max(X,a)\mid\min(X,a))$ is... a constant? Then this answer is wrong.

Comment: This basically reports the task on computing $E(X\mid\min(X,a))$, which may not be significantly easier than the original question. (As an aside, note that modifying a post once serious errors are signalled is good but doing it silently, without comment or notice, is a seriously nonconstructive practice.)